# Indeterministic Rock, Paper, Scissors?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, optimization, game-theory, gambling

Suppose we play Rock, Paper, Scissors but the outcome isn't deterministic and guaranteed. If you play Rock and I play Scissors, you will only beat me with some probability in $[0,1]$. Likewise for the other non-mirror possibilities. A mirrored outcome (e.g. both players play Rock) results in a draw.

What is the optimal strategy for playing this variant of the game?

Secondly, instead suppose that the mirrored outcomes (Rock plays against Rock) will result in a win for one player with a probability in $[0,1]$, exactly like the non-mirrored outcomes. Draws don't exist in this variation.

What is the optimal strategy for playing this variant of the game?

In both variations, it occurs to me that the win probabilities for a given player can be represented as a `3x3` matrix, with the diagonal as `0.5` in the first variant (even though a draw isn't a win for either player, but I think this should work), and diagonals in `[0, 1]` in the second variant.

In both variants, assume information symmetry and agreement on the probabilities between both players.

Not homework. The application is Starcraft meta-gaming in a context where the race pick isn't known up front and both players are strong at all the races.

---

These are my thoughts on a possible computational approach. Barring empirical data on actual tendencies, we could start with an assumption of your opponent's tendencies (say, [1, 0, 0], or [0.5, 0.4, 0.1]), and then find the optimal frequencies ([Rock %, Paper %, Scissors%]) to beat it via optimization. Iterate - keep finding the optimal frequencies to beat those from your last optimization step until you converge. I have no idea if this would converge on non-exploitable frequencies (I believe *not*), but it's the best I can think of right now. It *should* converge on a non-exploitable strategy in the trivial case where one option always dominates (e.g. Rock beats everything, we should converge to [1, 0, 0] frequencies), which is one nice property of this method. Another nice property of this method is that we should converge to [1/3, 1/3, 1/3] in the traditional Rock, Paper, Scissors game.

Comment: The easier way to think about this, is to use a matrix with 0's on the diagonal, and expected profits in other cells. E.g, If Rock wins with prob x over paper then in the cell (Rock, Paper) you will have 2x-1 for P1 and 1-2x for P2. For most values of the probabilities it will remain a zero-sum game, resulting in a mixed strategy equilibrium that puts more weight on the options that win with a higher probability. In some extreme cases you will get a pure strategy equilibrium. For example, if all probs are 0.5 any strategy is an equilibrium. If Rock always wins, Rock,Rock is an equilibrium.

Comment: In the case of a matrix that has a mixed strategy equilibrium (which I believe simply means that we need to use randomness in our strat?), how can we approach finding the optimal strategy? @GameTheorist1982

Comment: In a mixed-strategy equilibrium each player has to be indifferent between all actions that receive positive probability. There are two candidates for mixed strategy equilibria, depending on the winning probabilities, one in which the players only mix between two of the options and one in which the players are indifferent between all three options. Defining the choice probabilities as variables and using the indifference condition gives you a system of equations to solve.